# panda: compare two dates if both dates are date then date - date = days

Tags: pandas

I have two columns,

```
    AnalyseDatum_calc   erstellt am
0   05.01.2015          31.10.2014
1   SN not found        07.01.2015
2   05.01.2015          31.10.2014
3   05.01.2015          SN not found
4   05.01.2015          SN not found
5   05.01.2015          07.01.2015
6   SN not found        31.10.2014
7   SN not found        07.01.2015
8   05.01.2015          09.12.2014
```

i would like to comapre, if in both columns is date then date - date = days.

this is formel:

```
df4['Tage SM-Analyse_helper'] = np.where(((df4['AnalyseDatum_calc'] != 'SN not found') & (df4['erstellt am'] != 'SN not found')), (pd.to_datetime(df4['AnalyseDatum_calc'], format='%d.%m.%Y') - pd.to_datetime(df4['erstellt am'], format='%d.%m.%Y')).dt.days,'NOK')
```

i am getting error:

```
ValueError: time data 'SN not found' does not match format '%d.%m.%Y' (match)
```

what i am doing wrong?
thanks a lot for help

Answer (score 2):

You can use `pd.to_datetime` with `errors='coerce'` option:

```
(pd.to_datetime(df['AnalyseDatum_calc'], dayfirst=True,errors='coerce')
  - pd.to_datetime(df['erstellt am'], dayfirst=True,errors='coerce')
)
```

Output:

```
0   66 days
1       NaT
2   66 days
3       NaT
4       NaT
5   -2 days
6       NaT
7       NaT
8   27 days
dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Comment: i need also "'NOK'" if NAN

Comment: chain that with `.fillna('NOK')`.

Comment: great and the last question,i am getting 66 days 00:00:00, but i would like to have only 66. How can i get only 66

Comment: ((pd.to_datetime(df4['AnalyseDatum_calc'], dayfirst=True,errors='coerce') 
                                 - pd.to_datetime(df4['erstellt am'], dayfirst=True,errors='coerce'))/ np.timedelta64(1, 'D')).fillna('NOK')

Comment: can you pls see my comment below, tnx fo your help. ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '-'

Answer (score 1):

Try the below:

```py
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

def validate_date(inp, date_format):
    try:
        return dt.datetime.strptime(inp, date_format)
    except ValueError:
        return None

data = {
    'AnalyseDatum_calc': ['05.01.2015', 'SN not found', '05.01.2015', '05.01.2015', '05.01.2015', '05.01.2015', 'SN not found', 'SN not found', '05.01.2015'],
    'erstellt am': ['31.10.2014', '07.01.2015', '31.10.2014', 'SN not found', 'SN not found', '07.01.2015', '31.10.2014', '07.01.2015', '09.12.2014'],
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['date_diff'] = df['AnalyseDatum_calc'].apply(lambda x: validate_date(x, '%d.%m.%Y')) - df['erstellt am'].apply(lambda x: validate_date(x, '%d.%m.%Y'))
```